# How to Manipulate Individual Object Instance Variables?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, object, instance

I have been learning Python as my first language for about two weeks now and I love it. I have been using Learn Python the Hard way, but when I hit Object Oriented Programming my brain just about exploded. I did many hours of research and I thought I finally got the gist, but now I am a little stuck.

I have created a very simple banking program, attempting to use Classes. I was doing fine, until I hit a big issue. As it is, it works (I have not posted the menu setup for brevity, but it does what I want as long as I only have these three objects.) There in lies the problem.

1. **Issue: How do I manipulate instance values if there are multiple instances. TLDR: How can I not hard code object references? 
   Please see the Transfer function in my main BankAccount Class: I hardcoded in the objects(accounts) saccount.balance and paccount.balance variables, but what if there were many different accounts? How would I be able to edit their balances aka do transfers?**

How can I make the Transfer() method correctly reference the instances they need to go to? Am I asking this right?
 Am I using OOP incorrectly?

What if there were multiple users or multiple bank accounts? like "daccount", "faccount" etc how would I manage their balances and transfers?

Please be gentle...

***Here is my main Class:***

```
class BankAccount:
    #### NO CLASS VARIABLES
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 500 #This is an instance variable

    def withdraw(self, amount): 
        self.balance = self.balance - amount
        print "You withdrew %d dollars\n" % amount
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self, amount): 
        self.balance += amount
        print "You deposited %d dollars\n" % amount
        return self.balance

    def transfer(self, amount):  ### Here is our problem
        print "Where would you like to transfer money from?" 
        answer = raw_input("1.) From CHECKINGS to SAVINGS\n2.)From SAVINGS to CHECKINGS\n >>>")
        if answer == "1":
            baccount.balance -= amount #What would I do if there were many accounts?
            saccount.balance += amount #I originally tried this as SavingsAccount.balance, but that would be a "Class Variable" correct?
        elif answer == "2":
            saccount.balance -= amount 
            baccount.balance += amount 
        else: 
            menu()**

    def printbal(self):
        print "Your balance is currently %d dollars." % self.balance
        return self.balance
```

Here are my two subclasses (A minimum balance checkings, and a savings)

```
class MinBalAccount(BankAccount): #This is a BankAccount and has a MinBal
    def __init__(self, minbalance): #This sets our minbalance during 'instantation'
        BankAccount.__init__(self) #This gives us the variable self.balance 
        print "ATM INITIALIZED. WELCOME TO SKYNET BANK"
        self.minbalance = minbalance #Sets the minimum balance for this minbalaccount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        while self.balance - amount < self.minbalance: #THis allows for a loop, 
            print "Apologies, you must maintain a balance of 1.00" 
            print "If you withdraw %d from your current balance of %d it will leave you with a balance of %d dollars." % (amount, self.balance, self.balance - amount)
            print "Please Re-Enter The AMOUNT You would like to withdraw"
            amount = int(raw_input("\nAmount:"))

        BankAccount.withdraw(self, amount)
        self.printbal() #We can do this because we inherited it from out parent class. We could also write it as MinBalAccount.printbal(self) or BankAccount.printbal(self)


class SavingsAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self,minbalance,balance):
        self.minbalance = minbalance
        self.balance = balance
paccount = BankAccount()
baccount = MinBalAccount(1.00)
saccount = SavingsAccount(300, 500)
```

Comment: Are you asking what you would do if you had lots of instances of BankAccount and you wanted to do transfer() with all of them?

Comment: Rather than do a transfer with all of them... let's say I had 

'paccount = BankAccount()
baccount = MinBalAccount()
saccount = SavingsAccount
iaccount = InvestingAccount()(I would create a menu item to "open" and instantiate an InvestingAccount class object)'



I now have an extra class instance(Investing Account) that my transfer method as it is couldn't handle. How would I be able to allow my user to do operations on that account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make the Transfer() method correctly reference the instances they need to go to? Am I asking this right?
>   Am I using OOP incorrectly?

You declare object references in Python the same way you do any other variable, you run the constructor of the class and assign it to a value. If you want to transfer from one account and into another account (regardless of the account), you want to pass the object references as arguments to the function in the method (assuming these accounts are separate from each other).

Consider the design of your BankAccount class: You're currently using your transfer method to transfer from two fixed accounts. If you want to transfer from the current BankAccount object (IE "self"), to another account (whichever one is passed to the method), you would write your method like so:

```
def transferTo(self, otherAccount, amount):
  if (self.balance >= amount):
    self.balance -= amount
    otherAccount.balance += amount
```

Then when you call this method, you simply indicate which account to transfer the funds to.

```
baccount.transferTo(saccount, 100)
```

And you're done! I would recommend keeping the IO operations (such as asking the user for input) outside of these methods since you could want to perform transfers that don't need user input.

You can treat object references the same way you could any other value. Therefore you can pass them to any method, place them in a list, etc.

> What if there were multiple users or multiple bank accounts? like "daccount", "faccount" etc how would I manage their balances and transfers?

You should separate the concept of an AccountHolder from each BankAccount. An AccountHolder may have multiple BankAccounts, and each BankAccount is then provided it's own balances, number, etc. You can assign class instances to instance variables in the method of a class. The AccountHolder class should have a list of BankAccount objects, and provide some basic methods that return certain key accounts (such as a checkingAccount() method). A constructor like this would work well for a User:

```
class AccountHolder:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.user_name = name
    self.checking = BankAccount()
    self.savings = MinBalAccount()
```

I believe, however, that the key to your question is to pass the object references as arguments to methods, allowing you to more generically treat each instance of a BankAccount. Understandably this is your first real encounter with OOP, so it's certain to be overwhelming. I wish you luck!

Comment: I think this is the closest thing that I can find to what I was looking for. 
I guess I was going about it the wrong way. I should have made the transfer method more versatile(scalable?) with a destination.

So if I were to create the AccountHolder class, and instantiate it, I could just use the destination portion as self.checking/self.savings. 

Is that what you were getting at?

Comment: That sounds accurate. Though you would want the transferTo() method to be in the BankAccount class, and the AccountHolder class should contain multiple BankAccount objects. You can eliminate the need to hardcode each account by using arguments in the method signature as the reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your transfer function. It needs 1) the amount 2) the destination account

```
    def transfer(self, amount, destination):  ### Here is our problem
        self.balance -= amount
        destination.balance += amount
```

And add the following code at the end

```
print "Where would you like to transfer money from?" 
answer = raw_input("1.) From CHECKINGS to SAVINGS\n2.)From SAVINGS to CHECKINGS\n >>>")
amount = int(raw_input("Amount to transfer ? "))
if answer == "1":
    baccount.transfer(amount, saccount)
elif answer == "2":
    saccount.transfer(amount, baccount)
else: 
    menu()**
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO you're running into an issue here because `transfer()` isn't really a good interface for a `BankAccount` instance. `withdraw()` and `deposit()` make sense on their own, but `transfer()` would at least require passing another argument, rather than hard-coding a global variable (in general i try to avoid using global variables).

What I would do instead is to have another class e.g. `User` which owns the `paccount`, `baccount`, `saccount` variables, in addition to the `transfer()`, `deposit()`, and `withdraw()` methods which guide you through the menu e.g.:

```
class User:

    def __init__(self):
        self._paccount = BankAccount()
        self._baccount = MinBalAccount(1)
        self._saccount = SavingsAccount(300, 500)

    def deposit(self, amount):
        num = input('Where do you want to deposit your money? 1) Savings 2) MinBal 3) Checking').strip()
        if num == '1':
           self._saccount.deposit(amount)
        ...

    def transfer(self, amount):
        print('Where would you like to transfer money from?')
        ...


user = User()
user.deposit(200)
user.transfer(500)
```

Comment: This seems to be what the other people are saying too. I need to create a user class that OWNS their own accounts. 
This is definitely helping. 

Thank you for the answer +1